# Conditional testing in Cypress - check if cy.xpath-element has class value

Tags: class, xpath, automated-tests, conditional-statements, cypress

What I want to do: I want to click a button. Then some element expands, and the button class name is changing. I only want to expand the element if not done yet.

I have to use cy.xpath, which makes it more complicate.

```
if (cy.xpath('//div[1]/button').should('have.class', 'it-is-focused'))
{
   // do something
}
```

This code is not working, because the class is not available. An error is thrown.

With .then() implemented

```
cy.xpath('//div[1]/button').then(($btn) => { 
    if($btn.hasClass('abc-focused')) {   
         // do something
    }
    else {
         // do something else
    }
})
```

Problem, if-bracket is never executed. `$btn.hasClass('abc-focused')` seem not to work. But the class is available in the DOM of this button.

Comment: Note that Cypress is _asynchronous_; `cy.xpath` doesn't run immediately and return the element, it adds a task to Cypress's to-do queue. Have a look at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases to understand the model a bit better.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hi, should I use .then then?

Comment: @jonrsharpe With .then I still get the error of missing item.

Comment: Please give a [mre] of that, then.

Comment: I added some code.

Comment: No, a MRE. What are you testing? _What_ error? Also you don't need "Edit", people can look at the history if they care.

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise. :/  Added information.

Comment: I am also facing same issue as that if() block is not executed. I need to check if class has "radio ng-star-inserted" but it's not going inside the if condition. Any help?